# TV Everywhere apps for Samsung Gear VR

Tags: streaming, mobile, phone, vr

TV Everywhere is cable and satellite providers' answer to the practice of cord-cutting, i.e. using Internet streaming services as a substitute for subscribing to cable or satellite services.  TV Everywhere refers to websites or apps that allow you to stream cable TV shows and movies, but require you to log in to your cable or satellite provider before doing so.

My question is, are there any TV Everywhere apps for the Samsung Gear VR headset?  The reason I ask is that I do a lot of my TV watching in virtual reality nowadays, and I'd like to watch two cable shows, the Twin Peaks revival on Showtime and Season 3 of 12 Monkeys on Syfy, using my Samsung Gear Gear VR headset.  So are there any apps that allow for streaming full episodes of Showtime and Syfy episodes through Gear VR?